# sudo like in Ubuntu (for Debian and other Linuxes)

Tags: ubuntu, debian, password, sudo

I personally like the default sudo behavior of Ubuntu:
- Root login impossible
- "admin" group granted "ALL=(ALL) ALL"
- users in the "admin" group are asked for their user password (not a root password) when using sudo.

[I like it, because this way, there's no root password to be shared among several people. There may be good reasons for other opinions, too - but that shouldn't be the topic of this question.]

Now I'm trying to re-create this behavior in Debian Etch. It basically works, but there's one important difference: Debian doesn't ask for a password. It should ask for the user's password.

I edited the sudoers file to be exactly the same as in Ubuntu, and I added a user to the newly created "admin" group. What else do I have to do to get the Ubuntu behavior in Debian (and other Linuxes)?

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem solved itself by waiting 15 minutes...
It works now, it simply kept the password alive for 15 minutes - which is normal, but I didn't know, that it even keeps it after a logout/login. I didn't expect this at all.

Everything's working fine now, thanks for the answers! (Can/should I somehow close this question?)

Comment: Since you provided the best answer, you can click the "check mark" next to your name.

Comment: Warner: He will have to wait a couple days before it lets him I think

Comment: Ok, thanks. When I click the check mark, it tells me, that I have to wait two days before I can accept my own answer. I'll mark it in my calendar.

Comment: When testing sudo you can use sudo -k to forget the login success instead of waiting 15 minutes.

Comment: chris_l: You can also run the search `user:2561 hasaccepted:0` every once and a while, putting in your user id, to keep on top of those.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there is no NOPASSWD anywhere in the sudoers file?

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't ask the password, you are root. 
I have the configuration working :

visudo

```
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

/etc/group

```
admin:x:1000:user1,user2
```

Answer (score 0):

The 15 minutes is the default length of time that the `sudo` timestamp will be valid. This timeout can be manipulated from the command line and also be set in the `sudoers` file.

To "cancel" the timeout so that the next use of `sudo` will request a password, use the command:

```
sudo -k
```

Alternately, if you want to extend the current timeout - that is, restart the timeout "timer" - use this command:

```
sudo -v
```

If the timeout is 15 minutes, after the `sudo -v` command you'll have 15 minutes before the password is asked for again.

In the `sudoers` file, the timeout can be set like this:

```
Defaults timestamp_timeout=10
```

(This sets the timeout to 10 minutes.)